# I created a ripple account ... what next? (how do I start?)

Tags: ripple

I have a ripple client set up, but I can't do anything useful such as viewing the order book etc.  Since the site is in beta, BTC and other currencies are not supported... only ripples.

Basically I know I need to give people my address of `rPZhwqx7kQdssJD6i3cnEpd9kQ1Tofzjkx` to get ripples, but I don't know who to contact or how to get started.

The teaser website and hype around the Ripple technology hasn't gotten me to pour over every detail of the Ripple wiki, so please forgive me if I missed it.

So how do I get started?

Comment: And yes, to even activate your account you need somebody to send you at least 300 XRPs

Comment: Yep, that is why I added my ripple address in the question hoping someone would throw some my way  ;)

Comment: 40,000 XRPs are given away here, read the rules in the orginal post carefully tho https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145506.0

Comment: @AlexKravets  Thanks, I don't check BitcoinTalk as often as I should.  Lots of noise.  Not enough signal for me.

Comment: If your account was created before Feb 19th and you can  actually post in the forum you will get your 40,000 XRPs (was 50,000 last week)

Comment: @Downvoter (presumably Stephen G.;) By majority vote, [Ripple questions are on topic.](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/356/1878)  Bitcoin is open to other crypto currencies just as stack overflow is open to other languages besides MSFT.

Comment: @makerofthings7 he is clearly abusing this site, but this site doesn't care. Not that I am surprised. http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/357/abusing-close-votes

Answer (score 1):

To see an active Bitstamp BTC IOUs vs. XRP market do the following:

Advanced -> Trade -> change issuer

Enter rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B which should then fill in BTC Bitstamp.net

Click on "Order Book" to see BTC/XRP offers.

Comment: That is in fact how to get started now that his account is funded.

Comment: It worked! Using rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B did indeed open the door to trading. Hmm, now how does one get their Bitcoins out of Ripple?

Comment: It worked more! I was able to open a Bitstamp account and then use the deposit from Ripple option generating a Ripple-acceptable address. Ripple indeed delivered Bitcoins to Bitstamp and from there it was easy to send them to my personal wallet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems someone funded your account.

```
  "account_data" : {
     "Account" : "rPZhwqx7kQdssJD6i3cnEpd9kQ1Tofzjkx",
     "Balance" : "39999999940",
     "Flags" : 0,
     "LedgerEntryType" : "AccountRoot",
     "OwnerCount" : 1,
     "PreviousTxnID" : "B2D32CF4212D43299C3ACF425B1CFF1CA32B7C103D759757A191A1DBAD722B99",
     "PreviousTxnLgrSeq" : 409732,
     "Sequence" : 7,
     "index" : "91578FC2E59952476945E54C91B0F462C479F86F14382A7AD86C963EAC5001E2"
  }
```

You should be able to transact without a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I went to the forums and got funded.  I then sent coins to myself, and ended up loosing some.  Not sure if that is expected.

Comment: Also I keep trying on funding my Bitstamp account but my ripples keep getting returned.  I thought this was because bitstamp wasn't trusted, but I made sure it was.  I'm lost and kinda gave up.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Each transaction costs 10 drops (a drop is a millionth of a ripple). Your balance above is in drops. If you mouse over the amount in the client, it will show the full amount. Why would you want to send ripples to Bitstamp? What purpose would that serve? Gateways are for currencies other than ripples (like dollars, Euros, Bitcoins, silver, and so on).

Comment: I have no idea why I'd want to send it to Bitstamp.  I have no idea what to do with a Ripple or why I need one. So I just tried sending them somewhere... maybe I'd end up with BTC.

Comment: @makerofthings7: If you want to trade XRP for BTC, use the "Trade" option in the client. You can then use a gateway to redeem BTC inside the Ripple network for actual Bitcoins.